# You have no background-color set (or background-color is set to transparent) but you have set a color

Tags: css, xhtml, w3c, w3c-validation

I'm getting this Warning (it's not a error, my CSS is valid).

I choosed full report just to check to validate

> You have no background-color set (or
>   background-color is set to
>   transparent) but you have set a color.
>   Make sure that cascading of colors
>   keeps the text reasonably legible.

What is this and how to solve. I'm getting this on total 57 selectors.

Answer (score 4):

Good explanation @graphicdevine on why the warnings are there.

Instead of hard-coding

```
background-color: #xxx;
```

for each tag, I read on a [forum](http://www.htmlforums.com/css/t-resolved-you-have-set-a-color-but-no-background-color-type-warnings-102470.html) that suggested putting this in:

```
background-color: inherit;
```

Also, anywhere you set a background color but not a text color, put in:

```
color: inherit;
```

It resolved all of those type of warnings for me.

Answer (score 1):

It covers theoretical problem when font colour is same as the backgound, i.e:

```
background-color: #fff;
color: #fff;
```

You don't need to worry about it, but if you want to get rid of the warrning I'm guessing just set the background colour as per the message.

Comment: It is a real problem. It crops up most often when authors assume people have their default main background colour set to white, but it can also conflict with user stylesheets.

Comment: Good point. What about background colour of the elements inside? Does *every* div need a background then if you set css color property on it..?

Comment: You don't know what the user has configured their browser to do. They might have `p { background: white; color: black }`. In general, always specify both if you can.

Comment: So * { background-color:#fff; color:#000; } would probably fix the problem? Declare it in first line, and then overwrite it by following rules.

Comment: No, it wouldn't help at all. The cascade matters. Having a background colour is applied to an element in the least specific part of the cascade has little impact.

Comment: doesn't work: Warning: `'Same color for “background-color” and “color”`

Answer (score 1):

Add `background-color:#/*whatever you want*/;` to all 57 selectors and you should be fine.

Comment: `html { color: #000; background: #FFF; min-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 1px; font-size: 100%; }` is already defined as a first thing in my css. even though i'm getting this warning

Comment: A "reset" isn't going to help.

Comment: Fair enough, then just add the rule to your other selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You solve it by:

> Make[ing] sure that cascading of colors keeps the text reasonably legible.

It's a warning that there *might* be something wrong, but that no tool is capable of discerning whether or not there actually *is* anything wrong.

(And of course, 'reasonably legible' is pretty open to interpretation. I use [colour contrast analyser](http://www.visionaustralia.org.au/info.aspx?page=628), many other, similar tools exist.)